# Regex '''string''' to <b>string</b>

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to replace `'''string'''` with `<b>string</b>`

this one wont work: `'/'''(.*?)'''/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to escape the single quotes with backslashes:

```
'/\'\'\'(.*?)\'\'\'/'
```

Or just use double quotes in which case you don't have to worry about escaping single quotes:

```
"/'''(.*?)'''/"
```

Comment: thanks. do you maybe know why the same wont work with: "/[[(.*?)]]/"

Comment: @Dremex, the square brackets introduce a character class unless they are escaped.  Try '/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/' instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "guns '''hurt''' people";

echo preg_replace ("/'''(.*)'''/", '<b>$1</b>', $string);
```

Comment: You'd need to escape the square brackets as well... "/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/" Square brackets are used for character classes. http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.squarebrackets.php